# Dictionary/Hashmap......... what on earth is happening?

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashmap

```
else if (!registryData.ContainsKey(keyName))
{
    keyInvolved = new RegistryKy(keyName);
    lock (registryDataLock)
    {
        registryData.Add(keyName, keyInvolved);
    }
    processInvolved = new Proces(procInvolved);
    keyInvolved.addProcessToDict(processInvolved);
}
```

keyName is a String which represents a registry key. keyInvolved is the actual registry key object.

I'm being told that im adding a key which already exists, yet i have already checked to see whether it is in there or not???

Comment: Maybe you could add what language you're using?

Comment: Actually can you put how to define RegistryKy please? I answered below, but I should really look at RegistryKy definition to be sure!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a stab in the dark, but the fact that you've got a `lock` on `registryDataLock` says to me that this is multi-threaded. Is it possible that another thread is adding the key to the dictionary after the call to `ContainsKey` but before the call to `Add`?

Also, the similarly-named variables make this code rather hard to read...

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `ContainsKey` and `Add` within the same `lock` block, otherwise another thread can add the key between the time you call `ContainsKey` and you acquire the lock. Here's one way to do it:

```
// check to see if the key exists
else if (!registryData.ContainsKey(keyName))
{
    bool foundKey;
    // lock the dictionary
    lock (registryDataLock)
    {
        // make sure another thread didn't add the key while waiting on the lock
        if (!(foundKey = registryData.ContainsKey(keyName)))
        {
            keyInvolved = new RegistryKy(keyName);
            registryData.Add(keyName, keyInvolved);
        }
        // release the lock as soon as we're done with registryData
    }
    // now perform operations that need to be done when we've added
    // a key but without holding the registry lock
    if (!foundKey)
    {
        processInvolved = new Proces(procInvolved);
        keyInvolved.addProcessToDict(processInvolved);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be like this:

```
else if (!registryData.ContainsKey(kyInvolved))
{
    //keyInvolved = new RegistryKy(kyInvolved);
    lock (registryDataLock)
    {
        //registryData.Add(kyInvolved, keyInvolved);
        registryData.Add(kyInvolved, new RegistryKy(kyInvolved));
    }
    processInvolved = new Proces(procInvolved);
    keyInvolved.addProcessToDict(processInvolved);
}
```

Comment: The lock should really be before the ContainsKey check

Comment: This is wrong.  Another thread could come in right the lock and you're still screwed.